# How to count records from table in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

What i want to achieve is to save in db all search terms that come from a form when they don't exist in the db_table.

what it doesn't work is the 3rd step as seen in comments bellow.

```
    public function search(Request $request){
        $q = $request->get('q', 'Δεν υπαρχει');
        if (!$request->filled('q')) $q = 'Δεν υπαρχει';
        else{ 
            //1 First save in db all search terms @ table Searches
            $search_term = new SEARCH();
            $search_term->term = $request->get('q');
            $search_term->save();
            //2 Then return all relevant eshops
            $eshops = Eshop::orWhere('tags', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')->
                             orWhere('title', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')->
                             orWhere('link', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')->
                             get()->count();

            $count = $eshops->count();

            if($count == 0){
            //3 Lastly save in db all not found search terms @ table notfound
            $not_found_search_term = new NOTFOUND();
            $not_found_search_term->term = $request->get('q');
            $not_found_search_term->save();
            }

        }
        return view('eshops', ['eshops' => $eshops]);
    }
```

Comment: You are using `count()` twice. Once on your `Eshop` query and then again when assigning your `$count` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting next error after execute this
`Call to a member function count() on int`

This is because you duplicate `->count()`.

```
$eshops = Eshop::orWhere('tags', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')->
                             orWhere('title', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')->
                             orWhere('link', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')->
                             get()->count();

            $count = $eshops->count();
```